# How to type the Chinese in the Android emulator for Monkeyrunner?

Tags: android

I am using Monkeyrunner to do automation for Android devices.
But I don't know how to type Chinese? Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool
https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard.
It's ok for my to input Chinese now.
However, you should be careful about some specific Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

To change for chinese, just  long-press on an input field and choosing Input Method → Android Keyboard. you can also long-press on the bottom-left key on the virtual keyboard.